# ASP.NET Core MVC custom validation ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

Validation:

```cs
public class MustContainTags : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var msg = (Message)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

            if (msg.Text == null)
                return new ValidationResult("This field is required.");

            var text = msg.Text;
            if (Regex.Matches(text, @"($\w+)").Count == 0)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Message must contain at least one tag.");
            }
            else
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }
    }
```

Model:

```cs
public class Message
    {
        ...
        [BsonElement("msg_text")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Message")]
        [MinLength(32, ErrorMessage = "Must contain at least 32 characters.")]
        [MaxLength(256, ErrorMessage = "Must contain no more than 256 characters.")]
        [MustContainTags(ErrorMessage = "Message must contain at least one tag.")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult PostMessage(Message model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                 //do things and redirect
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Technically looks fine, and it should work. Except it doesn't.

Built-in validation works as expected. When something is incorrect, red text appears under input and informs user something is wrong.

When all constraints are satisfied except `[MustContainTags]`, there is no error message, and `ModelState.IsValid = false`, which redirects us to view, instead of inform user what is wrong.

Edit

View:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="NewMessage">
    <div class="border p-3">
        @*<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>*@
        <div class="form-group row">
            <h2 class="text-info pl-3">Write new post</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Message.Title" class="ml-2"></label>
            <input asp-for="Message.Title" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Message.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Message.Text" class="ml-2"></label>
            <textarea asp-for="Message.Text" class="form-control" rows="6"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="Message.Text" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-8 offset-2 row">
            <div class="col">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info w-100"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Post message</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success w-100"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it might be better to use the override of IsValid that returns a bool.

```
    protected override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return false;

        string valueString = value as string;

        if (Regex.Matches(valueString, @"($\w+)").Count == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have also tried second option now, results are identical.

Comment: I have tried your sample code and not been able to recreate the problem. Which leads me to think that the problem is not what I thought. Could you add your view to the question?

Comment: view has been added. I have tried a few more variants, always the same result. Error is not appearing, just throws us to the view.

Comment: Have you looked into it or not? I'm afraid I will be forced to switch technology.

Comment: I used just what you've given here and it worked for me, so I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to create custom client side validation in ASP.NET. Only built in functions like `[Required]` are available. You can try bypassing it with javascript.